# Select all block level elements with css

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there an easy way to select all block level elements with CSS?

I want to put am 1.5 em margin between all block level elements in the main content area of my site

Right now I have code like:

```
#wrapper .content p, #wrapper .content ul, #wrapper .content div, #wrapper .content ol, #wrapper .content blockquote, #wrapper .content table {margin-top: 1.5em;}

#wrapper .content p:first-child, #wrapper .content ul:first-child, #wrapper .content div:first-child, #wrapper .content ol:first-child, #wrapper .content blockquote:first-child, #wrapper .content table:first-child {margin-top: 1.5em;}
```

Which is a royal pain in the rear to read or maintain...

I would like to replace it with something like:

```
#wrapper .content *:block + *:block {margin-top: 1.5em;}
```

Is this possible?

I can't use `* + *` because that will also catch inline elements, table cells, etc, and I don't want random margins being applied in the middle of paragraphs. I also can't use `#wrapper .content > *` because then it won't get nested `div` etc.

Comment: I think inline elements will ignore margins, no?

Comment: @George Garchagudashvili: Not exactly. Vertical margins on inline elements can affect baseline calculations, which can have catastrophic results in any parts of the layout that rely on inline-blocks or tables.

Comment: Your requirement is weird but not impossible. I would rather suggest you to assign specific classes to the elements you need a `margin` on or if you are dead sure to target all block elements than its better to list them down in your stylesheet and assign margin to them

Comment: @Mr. Alien: Indeed, having a selector that targets *any* block-level element sounds misguided. Why would one assume that just because an element is block-level, it is part of the content and therefore needs to have these margins? I can see why someone might want to apply similar margins to e.g. p, ul, figure, blockquote, in which case unfortunately the lack of a standardized `:matches()` pseudo means one has to spell out all the selectors in full. But that is no reason to select any element as long as it is block-level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with CSS; you can't select an element based on one of its CSS properties. You'll need to use JavaScript to select all elements with something like `getComputedStyle` or something similar, and then run some script logic based on what that finds.

The closest thing you can get to in CSS is selecting HTML *attributes*; things like `href` or `title`.

Answer (score 2):

```
:not(a):not(b):not(label):not(form):not(abbr):not(legend):not(address):not(link):not(area):not(mark):not(audio):not(meter):not(b):not(nav):not(cite):not(optgroup):not(code):not(option):not(del):not(q):not(details):not(small):not(dfn):not(select):not(command):not(source):not(datalist):not(span):not(em):not(strong):not(font):not(sub):not(i):not(summary):not(iframe):not(sup):not(img):not(tbody):not(input):not(td):not(ins):not(time):not(kbd):not(var) {border:1px solid red;}
```

not sure if I missed an element, but you get the idea. I think this should work.

Answer (score 0):

@tylerh answer is correct it's not possible to active in pure css in the way you ask for.

One possible workaround with css is to create a generic css class to handle your block level elements like `.block-element`

And then apply the margin styling with

```
#wrapper .content .block-element { margin-top: 1.5em; }
```

Comment: I would rather list all the block level elements in the stylesheet instead of adding a block-element class to an obvious block level element...

Comment: @mr-alien and you're free to do so. I would say, depending on your markup, `.block-element` would in most of my own implementations represent a grid row or a component-wrapper.  But it all depends on the way the markup and css is structured.

Answer (score -4):

> Is there an easy way to select all block level elements with CSS?

By default, the non-block elements ignore margins. So you answered to your question.

Comment: Not true. See the comments on the question.

Comment: Both of you ignore the context. Go insert(as author requested) margin top and bottom. See if the margins are ignored. And btw nice for you @BoltClock, you have lots of xp and you don't know what you are talking about, Have a great day! :)

Comment: I didn't said specific to what OP said, I replied to this statement which you wrote - *By default, the non-block elements **ignore margins**.*